# Is it possible to increase the max limit of 10 pc's to any number of times without making the user a domain admin?

Tags: active-directory, domain, group-policy, database-administration, limits

Normally a domain user has a maximum limit for 10 computers to join to a domain. But what i want to know is, is it possible (by joining a account to a group) to do this any number of times without making the user a domain admin?

Answer (score 1):

In order to not drive myself nuts I found the following, you should try to rtfw.

1. Click Start, click Run, type dsa.msc, and then click OK.
2. In the task pane, expand the domain node.
3. Locate and right-click the OU that you want to modify, and then click Delegate Control.
4. In the Delegation of Control Wizard, click Next.
5. Click Add to add a specific user or a specific group to the Selected users and groups list, and then click Next.
6. In the Tasks to Delegate page, click Create a custom task to delegate, and then click Next.
7. Click Only the following objects in the folder, and then from the list, click to select the Computer objects check box. Then, select the check boxes below the list, Create selected objects in this folder and Delete selected objects in this folder.
8. Click Next.
9. In the Permissions list, click to select the following check boxes:

   - Reset Password
   - Read and write Account Restrictions
   - Validated write to DNS host name
   - Validated write to service principal name
10. Click Next, and then click Finish.
11. Close the "Active Directory Users and Computers" MMC snap-in